# Querying a many to many relationship with filter and pagination in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, join, nested

I am trying to paginate over a list of blog posts and filter those based on a list of tags they might have in an SQLite database.

Posts and Tags have a n-to-n relationship so I created a PostTag relation table.

```
CREATE TABLE "Post" (
    "Id"    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    "Title" TEXT
);


CREATE TABLE "Tag" (
    "Id"    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    "Label" TEXT
);


CREATE TABLE "PostTag" (
    "Id"    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    "PostId"    INTEGER,
    "TagId" INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY("PostId") REFERENCES "Post"("Id"),
    FOREIGN KEY("TagId") REFERENCES "Tag"("Id")
);
```

Given the following data

```
INSERT INTO Post (Title) VALUES ('Post title 1'), ('Post title 2'), ('Post title 3');
INSERT INTO Tag (Label) VALUES ('news'), ('funny'), ('review');
INSERT INTO PostTag (PostId, TagId) VALUES (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 2), (3, 3);
```

I am trying to select 10 posts that have both the tags 'news' **and** 'funny' so I would like only 'Post title 1' to be returned (edit for clarification : I need post 1 to be returned twice here, once with the 'news' tag, and once with the 'funny' tag).

I am using DENSE_RANK to actually have 10 different posts in the results even though the join could return more than 10 rows.

The issue I have is how to manage the 'AND' operator on tags values, i.e. not returning posts that have only one of the tags. So here I would not want post 3 to be returned because it only has the 'funny' tag, not the 'news' tag.

Here is my best query so far (updated below), which will return posts having 'news' **or** 'funny' which is not what I want :

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT p.*, t.*, DENSE_RANK() OVER(order by p.id desc) rnk
    FROM Post p
    JOIN PostTag pt ON p.Id = pt.PostId
    JOIN Tag t ON pt.TagId = t.Id AND t.Label IN ('news', 'funny')
    ORDER BY p.id desc
) ranked
WHERE rnk <= 10
```

Please note that I am deduplicating and regrouping the results by posts afterwards using dapper, so having each post appearing several times is not real concern (please read update below for more details).

---

UPDATE:

The query must return a matching post as many times as the number of its associated tags (even though those tags may not be in the queried tags), something like :

```
Id          Title           Id:2            Label           rnk
1           'Post Title 1'  1               'news'          1
1           'Post Title 1'  2               'funny'         1
```

If later on, someone adds a tag to post 1 like so :

```
INSERT INTO Tag (Label) VALUES ('tech'); -- id is 4
INSERT INTO PostTag (PostId, TagId) VALUES (1, 4);
```

The result of the query should be

```
Id          Title           Id:2            Label           rnk
1           'Post Title 1'  1               'news'          1
1           'Post Title 1'  2               'funny'         1
1           'Post Title 1'  4               'tech'          1
```

So I can show the matching post with all its tags, even though the tag was not in the query.

I finally have something working, but it is horribly nested and I am sincerely wondering why this problem is ending up being so convoluted. Isn't there a way to count on ranks directly ?

```
select * from ( 
    select  *, dense_rank() over(order by p.id desc) rnk 
    from Post p 
    join PostTag pt on p.Id = pt.PostId 
    join Tag t on pt.TagId = t.Id 
    and postId in (
        select postId from (
            select dense_rank() over(order by pt2.PostId) rnk2,
            from PostTag pt2 
            join Tag t2 on pt2.TagId = t2.Id 
            where t2.Label in ('news', 'funny')
        )
        group by rnk2
        having count(rnk2) == 2 -- 2 being the number of tags requested
    ) order by p.id desc 
) 
ranked where rnk <= 10
```

Comment: Maybe my approach is bad, maybe I shouldn't try to return tags on separate post lines...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to give you one idea.

```
select * from (
    select p.*, t.*, dense_rank() over(order by p.id desc) rnk
    from Post p
    join PostTag on p.Id = PostId
    join Tag t on TagId = t.Id
    and postid in (select postid
                     from posttag join tag t on tagid = t.id
                     where label in ('news', 'funny')
                     group by postid having count(distinct tagid) > 1)
    order by p.id desc
) ranked
where rnk <= 10;
```

Comment: This works, thanks ! As I just said to forpas, I also needed potential other tags associated to post 1 to be returned too, which works with your query. I honestly have a hard time wrapping my head around it though, haha.

Comment: Replaced `count(*)` with `count(distinct postid)` in case the PostTag entries are allowed duplicate tuples.  I originally thought they are not allowed but the table structure allows them.

Comment: Sorry I had to un-accept your answer because the IN-subquery will never return more postIds than the number of different tags requested. This coincidentally worked on my very simple dataset but a soon as 2 posts are matching both the tags, only one of them would be returned.

Comment: Shouldn't the `> 1` be `== {number of tags queried}` instead ?

Comment: Or greater than one less the number if tags. Either way.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a simple group by post, like this:

```
select p.id, p.title
from posttag pt
inner join post p on p.id = pt.postid
inner join tag t on t.id = pt.tagid
where t.label in ('news', 'funny')
group by p.id, p.title
having count(distinct t.id) = 2
order by p.id limit 10
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/upYfLctEbXFwFSQskKTiix/1).

Comment: This is almost ok but I need to retrieve all the tags associated with the posts (and deduplicate afterwards). By the way if there was another tag, say '2019' attached to Post 1, it should also be in the result. @tonypdmtr's solution works with that constraint.

Comment: *I am trying to select 10 posts that have both the tags 'news' and 'funny'* this is what you asked and this is what this code does.

Comment: Ok my bad, I did not mention explicitely that I needed each post's separate tag being returned in the results.